# Setting image as background on Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am new to programming, and am having real difficulty with setting an image as a background in Tkinter. I saw a similar question to this and its solution was to add "ImageTk.PhotoImage" but error 'Name 'ImageTk' is not defined' appeared. Is there any other ways to do this?
Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Did you `import ImageTk`?

Comment: I just did and it says 'no module named "ImageTk"'

Comment: Also, you should check out [ask] and [mcve].  We need to see the code that you've tried in order to be able to really help.

Comment: `ImageTk` is a `PIL` class. Whatever tutorial you're reading, go over it more thoroughly.

Comment: try to download the following packages: python3-pil, python3-imaging-tk, pillow ... and whats yout S.O.? And post your code for better understanding